# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout on recyclerview inside fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout" error message.
I have recycleView inside fragment so I must have done something wrong on fragment1.java.

here is the code. I set adapter on the code as you can see, but I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private ArrayList<Bible> arrayList;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),  2);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = database.getReference("Bible");

    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Bible bible = snapshot.getValue(Bible.class);
                arrayList.add(bible);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.e("fragment1", String.valueOf(databaseError.toException()));//에러문 출력
        }
    });

    adapter = new BibleAdapter(arrayList, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);






    return rootView;
}
```

}

public class BibleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private  ArrayList<Bible> arrayList;
private  Context context;
private OnVerseItemClickListener listener;

public BibleAdapter(ArrayList<Bible> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnVerseItemClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.verse_item, parent, false);
    BibleViewHolder holder = new BibleViewHolder(view, listener);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BibleAdapter.BibleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(holder.imageView)
            .load(arrayList.get(position).getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.bibleType.setText(arrayList.get(position).getBibleType());
    holder.keysentance.setText(arrayList.get(position).getKeysentance());
    holder.verse.setText(arrayList.get(position).getVerse());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (arrayList!=null? arrayList.size():0);
}

public class BibleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView bibleType;
    TextView verse;
    TextView keysentance;

    public BibleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnVerseItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.bibleType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.bibleType);
        this.keysentance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.keysentance);
        this.verse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.verse);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onItemClick(BibleViewHolder.this, v, position);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have create adapter with empty arrayList, but never after that you update the list.

in adapter create swapData() method and call it when you have to refresh data or have refreshed data, in your case you will get it in onDataChange().

And also define adapter before adding listener:

```
adapter = new BibleAdapter(arrayList, getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                arrayList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Bible bible = snapshot.getValue(Bible.class);
                    arrayList.add(bible);
                }
                  adapter.swapData(arrayList);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Log.e("fragment1", String.valueOf(databaseError.toException()));//에러문 출력
            }
        });
```

in adapter class create method as:

```
public void swapData(ArrayList<Bible> filtersList) {
    if (filtersList != null) {
        this.arrayList.clear();
        this.arrayList.addAll(filtersList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put swapdata in adapter and changed RecyclerView.Adapter adapter to BibleAdapeter adapter. but still not working.

Comment: have you debug and check if arrayList is not empty?/

Comment: I change RecyclerView.Adapter adapter to BibleAdapter adapter on the code. and now it works partially. The image doesn't show so when I store image into database. I used gs link instead of https link because https link no longer exists. Do you know how to store image into database?